# Making offline version of web page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page i want that it should work offline also when the internet is connected it should cache the files and when we disconnect net it should work fine I am using manifest file for this.But its not getting done.Is there any way to solve this issue or i have to use some scripts to cache the data.
Its working fine on offline version for firefox only but not working on ipad device so how to solve this issue

Some manifest file code

```
 CACHE MANIFEST
 CACHE:
 index.html
 brd_icon.png
 newstyle_tester.css
 draxxin.pdf
 exede.pdf
 js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
 js/script.js
 js/jquery.queryloader2.js



 image/startbutton.png
 image/mockup_splash_1.png
 image/testing_file_3.png
 image/overview.gif
 image/strategy.gif
 image/draxxin.gif
 image/excede.gif
 image/reference.gif
 image/results.gif
 image/seperator.png
 image/overview_active.png
```

Below is the link of web page which is not caching data.

http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/

Comment: Inspector shows that the manifest is loading from cache on reload.

Comment: i did not get you so how to fix this issue

Comment: Chrome and safari (both webkit) are reporting loading from application cache on reload. Firefox (which sucks) is giving me problems.

Comment: i also want this for safari only i am using this for ipad only so how to fix it please

Comment: Ok firefox is working fine for me now. I can set it to offline, and your app still loads.

Comment: mean what to changes so offline works fine when tested on ipad when thers is no internet

Comment: I have not tested this on an ipad. All I know is that if I load it once online, then load it again offline, the manifest works and loads your app.

Comment: mean first time i load online connected to net and then turn off net and then again load it it will work

Comment: Sorry my friend...language barrier. Not sure what you are asking :-(

Comment: when i turn off internet and load again on safari ipad it says connect to net

Comment: http://www.morganmyers.com/iPad_apps/Fostera_PRRS/# i want like this site my site also work like this when i test it on ipad without net

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11135/discussion-between-user1383841-and-jdi)

Comment: Does the iPad even have an offline mode?